# Consuming from multiple queues at once with aioamqp

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-asyncio

Is it possible to consume multiple queues at once using one channel with aioamqp?

Disclaimer: I created an [issue](https://github.com/Polyconseil/aioamqp/issues/105) in the project issue tracker but I'm really wondering if what I'm doing makes sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I think that this feature is not available in AMQP protocol (assuming my understanding of the protocol is correct).</s>

If you wish to consume from a queue you have to issue `basic.consume` call on a channel. The required argument for this call is `queue_name` and it's a "blocking" (not blocking a connection but blocking a channel) call where response is an object from the queue.

Long story short: each consumer has to have an exclusive access to a channel while it's waiting for queue objects.

OK, so my initial thought was incorrect. After digging into [AMQP](https://www.amqp.org/resources/specifications) I found out that it actually does support multiple consumers over one channel. However it does allow servers to set their limits if desired. Unfortunately I couldn't find any info about RabbitMQ specific case. So I assume that there is no such limit. All in all: this is an issue with the library.

However the workaround is still valid: just create a channel per consumer. It should work just fine.

Comment: You'r right, I will just open multiple channels in parallel, since that's a cheap operation. Thanks!!

Comment: Pretty sure RabbitMQ supports consuming multiple queues from the same channel. They would all be delivered to the same callback though.

Comment: @eandersson Yeah, I've dug into AMQP spec and it seems that you are correct. Updated the answer.

Comment: I've created a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895872/asyncio-and-rabbitmq-asynqp-how-to-consume-from-multiple-queues-concurrently), just in case someone wants to step in. I've decided to drop aioamqp because judging from the comments in the bug tracker, the author is not happy at all with the current API design and some things are difficult to do.

Answer (score 2):

With [ammoo](https://github.com/mwfrojdman/ammoo) that works:

```
import asyncio

from ammoo import connect


async def consume(channel, queue_name):
    async with channel.consume(queue_name, no_ack=True) as consumer:
        async for message in consumer:
            print('Message from {}: {}'.format(queue_name, message.body))
            if message.body == b'quit':
                print('Consumer for queue {} quitting'.format(queue_name))
                break


async def main():
    async with await connect('amqp://localhost/') as connection:
        async with connection.channel() as channel:
            await channel.declare_queue('queue_a')
            await channel.declare_queue('queue_b')

            await asyncio.gather(
                consume(channel, 'queue_a'),
                consume(channel, 'queue_b')
            )
            print('Both consumers are done')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
# python3 test.py 
Message from queue_a: b'hello queue a'
Message from queue_b: b'hello queue b'
Message from queue_a: b'quit'
Consumer for queue queue_a quitting
Message from queue_b: b'another message for queue b'
Message from queue_b: b'quit'
Consumer for queue queue_b quitting
Both consumers are done
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library